# Regex split string into multiple parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

`133. Alarm (Peep peep)`

My goal is to split the string using regex into 3 parts and store it as a json object, like

```
{
   "id": "133",
   "Title": "Alarm",
   "Subtitle": "Peep peep"
}
```

I can get the number using

```
function getID(text){
  let numberPattern = /\d+/g;
  let id = title.match(numberPattern);
  if(id){
    return id[0];
  }
}
```

and the text between braces using

```
function getSubtitle(text){
  let braces = /\((.*)\)/i;
  let subtitle = title.match(braces);
  if(subtitle){
    return subtitle[1];
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if I can get the three values from the string using a single regex expression (assuming that I will apply it on a long list of that string shape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one function. `exec()` will return `null` if no matches are found, else it will return the matched string, followed by the matched groups. With `id && id[1]` a check is performed to not access the second element of `id` for when a match is not found and `id === null`.

The second element is used `id[1]` instead of `id[0]` because the first element will be the matched string, which will contain the dots and whitespace that helped find the match.

```js
var str = "133. Alarm (Peep peep)";

function getData(str) {
  var id = (/(\d+)\./).exec(str);
  var title = (/\s+(.+)\s+\(/).exec(str);
  var subtitle = (/\((.+)\)/).exec(str);

  return {
    "id": id && id[1],
    "Title": title && title[1],
    "Subtitle": subtitle && subtitle[1]
  };
}

console.log(getData(str));
```

Comment: In some cases it works, in others I get null on title `{ id: '1', Title: null, Subtitle: 'The Opening Chapter' }`

Comment: I edited it. Does it work now? Also, what's the string you are using to produce the incorrect result?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```js
const data = '133. Alarm (Peep peep)'

const getInfo = data => {
  let [,id, title, subtitle] = data.match(/(\d+)\.\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)/)
  return { id, title, subtitle }
}

console.log(getInfo(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
let partsPattern = /(\d+)\.\s*(.*[^[:space:]])\s*\((.*)\)/
```

Not sure if JS can into POSIX charsets, you might want to use `\s` instead of `[:space:]` (or even the space itself  if you know that there aren't any other whitespaces expected).

This should capture all the three parts inside the respective submatches (numbers 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: Yes replaceing `[:space:]` with `\s` worked, You are awesome