# Regular Expression just takes forever on a non recognized character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, xregexp

I have a crazy regular expression that I m trying to run which accepts all language characters and kanji characters as well. But is takes forever and 99% of the time just hangs my UI. I am really new to regular expression. Any help to fix this regular expression would be really helpful. Thanks.

```
RegExp = XRegExp("^(\\p{L}|[0-9\\n\\[\\]\\(\\)\\#\\*\\“\\-\\+\\\\\\/\\.\\s\\:\\_\\“\\”\\–\\?\\!\\,\\;\\'\\’\\‘\\&quot;\\&amp;\\¡\\¿\\«\\»\\„\\。\\、\\「\\」\\『\\』]|[\u3000-\u303F]|[\u3040-\u309F]|[\u30A0-\u30FF]|[\uFF00-\uFFEF]|[\u4E00-\u9FAF]|[\u2605-\u2606]|[\u2190-\u2195])+$")
```

Comment: you can split your RegExp into smaller parts to find out which part is causing the problem. Check the accept answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495994/regex-split-string-into-multiple-parts to see how to split the RegExp

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `^(a|b|c)+$` like patterns since the backtracking here will be much more extensive than in the case of a mere character class.

You can merge, concatenate all your single char patterns into a single character class:

```js
var pattern = "^[-–\\p{L}0-9\n[\\]()#*+\\\\/.\\s:_“”?!,;'’‘&quot;&amp;¡¿«»„。、「」『』\\u3000-\\u303F\\u3040-\\u309F\\u30A0-\\u30FF\\uFF00-\\uFFEF\\u4E00-\\u9FAF\\u2605-\\u2606\\u2190-\\u2195]+$";
```

It will work much faster.

Also, if you are using it to allow `&quot;` and `&amp;` as *char sequences*, you need to move them out of the character class:

```js
var pattern = "^(?:&(?:quot|amp);|[-–\\p{L}0-9\n[\\]()#*+\\\\/.\\s:_“”?!,;'’‘¡¿«»„。、「」『』\\u3000-\\u303F\\u3040-\\u309F\\u30A0-\\u30FF\\uFF00-\\uFFEF\\u4E00-\\u9FAF\\u2605-\\u2606\\u2190-\\u2195])+$";
```